# issues with the execution of functions following a Firebase Storage Reference in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using the following code to update a profile pic in Firebase:

```
    func saveProfileImage(_ userUID: String, _ completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
    let resizedImage = image.resized()
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(resizedImage, 1.0)

    ref = StorageReference.profileImages.reference().child(userUID)
    downloadLink = ref.description

    ref.put(imageData!, metadata: nil) {
        (metaData, error) in
        completion(error)
    }
    updateProfilePic(userUID)
}
```

updateProfilePic is a function made to trigger a childChanged so users download the new profile pic. It has not been working and I think it is because it is being called before the StorageReference has finished updating. Is there any way to ensure that the function is called only after the Reference is completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For code you need to call only when a completion block runs, you should put that said code inside the completion block, so change:

```
ref.put(imageData!, metadata: nil) {
        (metaData, error) in
        completion(error)
    }
    updateProfilePic(userUID)
```

to

```
    ref.put(imageData!, metadata: nil) {
        (metaData, error) in

        guard error == nil else {
           print("Error from adding to FIRDatabase: \(error)")
           return
        }

        self.updateProfilePic(userUID)
    }
```

If `updateProfilePic` must always be called after the completion block is successful

Comment: it seems that the question is answered, hopefully it fixes the broader problem as well

Comment: Quick replying indeed! haha

Comment: it works now thanks. It was a weird problem that I traced back to this cause

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that `updateProfilePic()` is called after the upload has completed, move it **into** the callback/completion handler:

```
func saveProfileImage(_ userUID: String, _ completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
    let resizedImage = image.resized()
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(resizedImage, 1.0)

    ref = StorageReference.profileImages.reference().child(userUID)
    downloadLink = ref.description

    ref.put(imageData!, metadata: nil) {
        (metaData, error) in
        completion(error)
        updateProfilePic(userUID)
    }
}
```